# If $\sum|a_n|<\infty$ and $\sum |b_n|<\infty$, is the sum $\sum_{k=0}^\infty \sum_{n=0}^\infty |a_n||b_{n+k}|<\infty$?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Suppose that $(a_n)_{n=0}^\infty$ and $(b_n)_{n=0}^\infty$ are complex numbers satisfying $\sum_{n=0}^\infty |a_n|<\infty$ and $\sum_{n=0}^\infty |b_n|<\infty$. Is the sum $\sum_{k=0}^\infty  \Big(\sum_{n=0}^\infty |a_n|\cdot |b_{n+k}|\Big)<\infty$? If not, are there further conditions on the $b_n$ to make the sum finite?

I don't have mathematica handy to test a few examples, and I don't have much of an intuition as to what the answer should be. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: The product you have formed is not very natural; it might be better to first think about $\sum |a_nb_n|$ or the cauchy product, $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}a_{n-k}b_k$. Facts about those should tell you about your series

Comment: @user25959 If $f(z)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} a_kz^{-k}$ and $g(z)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} b_kz^k$ then $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nb_{n+k}\right)z^k$ is the regular part of $f(z)g(z)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the sum is finite:
$$
\sum_{k=0}^\infty \bigg( \sum_{n=0}^\infty |a_n| |b_{n+k}| \bigg) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty |a_n| \sum_{k=0}^\infty |b_{n+k}| \le \sum_{n=0}^\infty |a_n| \sum_{j=0}^\infty |b_j| = \bigg( \sum_{n=0}^\infty |a_n| \bigg) \bigg( \sum_{j=0}^\infty |b_j| \bigg).
$$
The rearrangement in the first step is justified because all terms are nonnegative.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that:
$$\left(\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}|a_n|\right)\cdot\left(\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}|b_n|\right)=\sum_{m,n}|a_m b_n|$$
is finite and our sum is:
$$\sum_{\substack{m,n\\ m\leq n}}|a_m b_n|\leq \sum_{m,n}|a_m b_n|.$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Work with indexes in $\mathbb{Z}$ and reduce to a familiar problem.

First, extend $a_n$ and $b_n$ from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{Z}$ by zero.

Next, define $c_n\colon = a_{-n}$

Now your series becomes

$$\sum_{k}( \sum_{n} c_{-n} b_{n+k})$$

a  [Cauchy product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product). (add some absolute values to stay on track).